# Additive scene loading to UNet

Tags: unity, c#, networking, multiplayer, unet

I have a main scene where my player is loading as I start or join the server. On some player action, I want to load additive scenes in to my main scene. It is loading fine on the client, but not across the network. My other clients are unable to watch it.

I checked different links, and found [a forum post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unet-with-additive-scene-loading-and-different-scenes-for-each-client.383468/) and [a *Unity Suggestions* page](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/add-additive-scene-loading-to-unet). It seems, to me, that this *"Additive scene loading to UNet"* feature is not available in Unity.

If additive scene loading in UNet is not available, then what are the alternatives?

---

I am able to load scene through `[ClientRpc]`. Is this the correct way to do this?

```
[ClientRpc]
public void RpcLoadLevelAcrossNetwork() 
{
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
}
```

Comment: I would also like to point out that users may actually *follow* the "Unity Suggestions" link and *vote* on this feature, if they think it would be a good idea to simply have the feature available. At the present time, it appears this suggestion is still *active*, but has not been *reviewed*.

Comment: @Gnemlock Note that I have removed "is it available". what feeback link ? but it still available

Comment: @Gnemlock if it is available then why did you removed this? i am hardly understand your comments.

Comment: It is ***not*** available. That is why users are saying "this is ***not*** available" and "we ***should*** make this available".

Comment: @Gnemlock this is what i am asking and saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52645/discussion-between-gnemlock-and-mohammad-faizan-khan).

Comment: check updated question